# What is a headless user in AWS context?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have been running into this term time and time again and can't find suitable documentation for it. What is a headless user in terms of AWS and how does it compare to a regular user in IAM?

Comment: Link to an example of where you are encountering this term? Or include some context in your question?

Comment: You might be referring to roles, which aren't necessarily applied to users. If that's the case there's an enormous amount of role documentation.